# Alternative for IMAP search command

Tags: java, email, search, imap

I need an alternative for IMAP search command "**A search 1:* unseen not deleted**" since the email server is forbidding the search command. I tried using "**A status (unseen)**" but it always returns zero though there's an unread message. Is there any alternative for the command? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "forbidding the search command"?  And are you doing a roll-your-own IMAP client or using JavaMail?

Comment: Hello dkarp, I'm using k9mail as my email client. I found out that the search command is missing the uid parameter. Instead of "a search all", I used "a uid search all" and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your problem that the IMAP server doesn't support `SEARCH` at all, or that it doesn't like your particular `SEARCH` command?  If it's the latter, we can simplify:

```
A SEARCH UNSEEN UNDELETED
```

(as `1:*` is implicit).  Even simpler -- just in case the server doesn't like and-ing `SEARCH` terms together at all -- would be:

```
A SEARCH UNSEEN
B SEARCH DELETED
```

and logically doing the AND in your code.

The brute-force way of doing it is:

```
C UID FETCH 1:* FLAGS
```

and then picking out all the ones with neither `\Seen` nor `\Deleted`.  (I'm suggesting `UID FETCH` because a similar `FETCH` command will return `BAD` on an empty folder.)

Also, [you're not supposed to call the `STATUS` command on the currently-selected folder](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.3.10):

> Note: The STATUS command is intended to access the
> status of mailboxes other than the currently selected
> mailbox.  Because the STATUS command can cause the
> mailbox to be opened internally, and because this
> information is available by other means on the selected
> mailbox, the STATUS command SHOULD NOT be used on the
> currently selected mailbox.